# Pass Firebase Data to DetailView using CollectionViewCell _Swift

Tags: swift

I am using Firebase Database to keep my data there. I can save all of the items successfully and basically can see them in the database console. I can also populate the collectionView cell with the stored data.

The only problem is that I cannot pass the data to detail view successfully.

I have looked at my other iOS app where I segue from tableview to view controller successfully but couldn't make it work with the collectionView in this new app.

This is the view controller that gets the data from firebase database. **observeRecipes()** function prints out the data in the console.

```
class RecipesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var recipesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var recipes = [Recipe]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        recipesCollectionView.delegate = self
        recipesCollectionView.dataSource = self
        observeRecipes()

        IHProgressHUD.showImage(UIImage(named:"disabled")!, status: "Loading")

    }


    func observeRecipes() {

        let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "recipes")

        ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value as Any)

            var newRecipes: [Recipe] = []

            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                    let showTitle = dict["RecipeName"] as? String,
                    let showTime = dict["RecipeTime"] as? String,
                    let recipeImage = dict["RecipePhoto"] as? String,
                    let ingridients = dict["Ingridients"] as? String,
                    let firstImageViewURL = dict["imageOne"] as? String,
                    let firstIngridients = dict["firstIngridientList"] as? String,
                    let firstInstructions = dict["firstInstructionList"] as? String,
                    let secondImageViewURL = dict["imageTwo"] as? String,
                    let secondIngridients = dict["secondIngridientList"] as? String,
                    let secondInstructions = dict["secondInstructionList"] as? String,
                    let thirdImageViewURL = dict["imageThird"] as? String,
                    let thirdIngridients = dict["thirdIngridientList"] as? String,
                    let thirdInstructions = dict["thirdInstructionList"] as? String,


                    let url = URL(string:recipeImage),
                    let urlFirst = URL(string: firstImageViewURL),
                    let urlSecond = URL(string: secondImageViewURL),
                    let urlThird = URL(string: thirdImageViewURL) {
                    let recipe = Recipe(title: showTitle, time: showTime, recipeImageURL: url, ingridients: ingridients, firstImageViewURL: urlFirst, firstIngridients: firstIngridients, firstInstructions: firstInstructions, secondImageViewURL: urlSecond, secondIngridients: secondIngridients, secondInstructions: secondInstructions, thirdImageViewURL: urlThird, thirdIngridients: thirdIngridients, thirdInstructions: thirdInstructions)

                    newRecipes.append(recipe)
                }
            }
            self.recipes = newRecipes
            self.recipesCollectionView.reloadData()

        })

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recipes.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let recipeCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "recipeCell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell
        recipeCell.set(cell: recipes[indexPath.row])

        return recipeCell

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

         if segue.identifier == "showRecipeDetails" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! RecipeDetailViewController 
        destination.selectedRecipe = sender as! Recipe 
    }







    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = recipesCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showRecipeDetails", sender: cell)
       // performSegue(withIdentifier: "showRecipeDetails", sender: indexPath)


    }
}

}
```

This is the detailViewController

```
class RecipeDetailViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


    var recipes = [Recipe]()
    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var selectedRecipe: Recipe?

    // Recipe Details
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ingridientsLabel: UILabel!

    //General Outlets & Variables
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var closeButtonView: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.delegate = self

        recipeTitleLabel.text = selectedRecipe?.title

    }
```

Below is the code that I have been using for prepareForSegue in my other app which works fine. I have tried to tweak this to fit into collectionView but somehow I cannot get it work.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
            let destination = segue.destination as! StoryDetailsViewController
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                destination.selectedStory = self.posts[indexPath.row]
                print(indexPath.row)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I updated the code with solution that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showRecipeDetails", sender: recipes[indexPath.item])
```

---

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showRecipeDetails" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! RecipeDetailViewController 
        destination.selectedRecipe = sender as! Recipe 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have got a collectionView instead of a tableView. So self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow doesn't work. 

When I change the tableView to recipeCollectionView it throws an error since collectionView doesn't have a member "indexPathForSelectedRow". It has this "indexPathsForSelectedItems" but this throws an another error on the destination.selectedRecipe line.

Comment: Can you also explain why it is not correct to extract data from the cell? I just want to know why so it sticks to my mind for the next time.

Comment: see edit.................., view shouldn't be related to extract model , you need to directly interact with the array

Comment: Thanks @Sh_Khan, both for the solution and explanation. it worked fine. I can now pass the data successfully.